# How to respond to "tell us about yourself" in an interview?

Tags: interviewing

I have been job hunting for a few months, as of writing. I have gone through a number of interviews, in some of which the interviewer/hiring manager has asked "could you tell us about yourself?"/"what have you been doing over the past XXX period" (or phrased similarly.)

As someone who is graduating from university, has presented all my experience, education, skills and experience on my CV, and may have sent a cover letter, and filled out a few screening questions/forms before the interview, I've found these questions to be mildly insulting (although I will never show it in the interview, only when I reflect afterwards)- as it comes across to me that the interviewer has not gone to the effort of glancing at my CV and seeing that I have ABC education and XYZ experience. When I am asked these questions, I often retell most of what is already on my CV (with one or two extra details that don't add much). Most of the time, the recruitment process progresses.

Am I missing something for these questions, and should I pursue jobs where these sort of questions are asked?

Comment: Maybe they want to test your tolerance level for what you would consider "stupid questions"? Or maybe they want to see what you instinctively talk about first. Or maybe they don't have time to read each resume thoroughly.

Comment: A CV is to get your foot in the door, an interview is your opportunity to show how you would be the best fit for the position.  Any competent interviewer will ask these sort of questions regardless of what you wrote on your CV.

Comment: I assume you're a software developer. Think of this question as a checksum. It verifies that you're the right person. That the interviewer received the right resume.  That the interviewer is interviewing you for the right position (and not the 3 other positions that may be open). Additionally, this question breaks the ice and should be easy to answer even if you're nervous. And if you're crazy, or if you didn't write your own resume, or if you lied, it may come out in your voice or in your body language or in the way that you chose to answer this particular question.

Comment: You just be able to **make small-talk**.  All they want is a VERY SIMPLE two-sentence answer. "Well I grew up in Japan. I'm married with two kids. My wife's actually a doctor. As you can see I've been programming pinball machines for eight years now. That's me!"  ITS JUST SOUNDS - if you truly, profoundly, don't "understand smalltalk" amongt humans, read a book on it and fake it.

Comment: Just wanted to comment; I have had the same trigger reaction of annoyance at these questions before. It hits you as a sudden bolt of generality when you came prepared for perhaps more specific Q's. It can make you stutter because 'yourself' just has too much scope, you need to make choices on what to relay. However, I agree that ultimately recruiters want what the accepted answer is mentioning; and this Q is common enough to warrant pre-preparing a response to it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the most common opener question in any job interview for any applicant. They ask for exactly that: Tell us about yourself. They have read your resume, sometimes througoutly, sometimes just skimmed through. Doesn't matter. Now they want to hear it from your perspective. Not just the hard facts, but how you see yourself. What you have done until now, what are you proud about, where is your focus.

NEVER react annoyed, this would irritate every interviewer. See it as a friendly invitation to talk about yourself. What makes you special, what are you passionate about (Bonus points: Why are you passionate about wanting to work for that company). Talk about more than just the hard facts. Show them the human behind the CV.

Comment: Don’t just summarize your resume.  This is the opportunity for your crafted “elevator pitch” about yourself and why you are perfect for this role.

Comment: Do you think they are interested in private interests or in work-related topics? Both?

Comment: @Ben, they are interested in hearing about who you are, the person, and how you might fit into what the team and company are trying to do. What about _you_ would make you a good fit for the position?

Comment: I'm glad I was asked that only once in all my interviews..  I really wouldn't know what to tell. Tbh, I'm also too lazy to think about what to tell as I have (from my pov) more important things on my mind :)

Answer (score 3):

Interviews especially first round interviews aren't so much about seeing if you're qualified for the job. If they thought you weren't you likely would not be there, they are about interacting with HR/the hiring manager/potential coworkers and seeing if you fit with them and they think you can work well in their team.

Tell me about yourself is just a general opening question for you to present in words instead of bullet point why you think you'll fit into the company.

Read the job description note what they talk about that's unique from other companies in that position and explain your experience with those policies/technologies/ect.

Read up on the company and know what they do, know if they like to talk about their culture or mission, if their web presences often speaks about things like that you'll likely want to mention how you fit in with that during an interview.

Answer (score 2):

First, this seems to be a common complaint among new computer-workers on SE Workplace:

> I've found these questions to be mildly insulting... it comes across
> to me that the interviewer has not gone to the effort of glancing at
> my CV...

Well, they probably haven't, so you need to get over this. Maybe there's a stack of a hundred resumes and they don't have the capacity to read and memorize all of them. Or they have a huge backlog of critical tasks today and got handed your resume 5 minutes ago. Or they think, "well I'm talking to him anyway, I'll just get it straight from the person".

*Most* human beings *don't* work like the "don't repeat yourself rule" from *Pragmatic Programmer*, and you'll be frustrated forever if you expect that.

More essentially, any time you're given a chance to talk in any venue, you should have a preplanned script of a few key talking points that you're trying to convey in the interaction. In the case of a job interview, you are trying to sell yourself to the company. So when given the floor you should pitch the top couple of items that would make you valuable to this specific company. Sell how your experience interfaces specifically with the work they do. Even if the question wasn't ostensibly about that, bend it a bit to your sales pitch.

Of course, the company also needs to sell itself to you, and there should be an opportunity for you to ask and get answers in the reverse direction, but that's a separate question.